# Insert aws urls into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I currently have a working audio player that uses paperclip attachments to upload to aws. I want to access all the urls for all tracks and insert them in an array or variable for use with my js audio player. Below is the following code that I have tried:

```
//incorrect code
 @tracks.each do |m|
  @tracks_url_list = m.audio
 end
```

I have also tried

```
//incorrect code
@tracks.each do |m|
  @tracks_url_list = Array[m.audio]
 end
```

When I implement

```
<% @tracks.each do |m| %>
  <%= m.audio %>
<% end %>
```

In the index.html.erb it displays
http://s3.amazonaws.com/musicstreamdata/tracks/audios/000/000/008/original/11_Acid_Rain_%28Prod._by_Jake_One%29_%28DatPiff_Exclusive%29.mp3?1457290530

and other track links show as well. However, when I try to store it inside a variable or array, it only shows one url for one track. I'm probably missing something obvious, but how do I get it so that I can store all the urls from my tracks in an array like this:

```
@track_url_lists = [track_one_url, track_two_url, track_three_url, etc. ]
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of following:

```
@tracks_url_list = @tracks.collect(&:audio)
```

or

```
@tracks_url_list = @tracks.inject([]) each do |url_list, track|
  url_list << track.audio
  url_list
end
```

Refer to [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) for more info